# phpmyadmin showing code. php is working

Tags: ubuntu, apache-http-server, php, phpmyadmin

I am running Ubuntu 18.04, Apache 2.4.29, php 7.2. The problem is when I try to load phpmyadmin all it shows is code. I know php is working cause phpinfo works perfectly. https://www.aaackley.com/phpinfo.php works https://www.aaackley.com/phpmyadmin shows php code. I have tried 3 versions of php including the 5.0 snapshot all doing the same thing.

Comment: With a different web server, I need my PHP files to have `<?php` as the first line, and `?>` as the last line. I don't know if Apache needs this, but do you have it?

Comment: I have short tags enabled but yes they have long tags

Comment: You should check your setup. There is at least some chance you are attempting to run `PHPMyAdmin` from a directory/path that you haven't specified should be allowed to run scripts.

Answer (score 1):

Try configuring FastCGI:

```
sudo a2enmod proxy_fcgi setenvif
sudo a2enconf php7.0-fpm
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: I have tried this multiple times. Says already enabled for each one. Still showing code for phpmyadmin but other php working.

Comment: @Archie have you tried purging PHPMyAdmin and reinstalling it? Seems to me as the best option as it could be an incompatible configuration.

Comment: Thanks Dejan. Just tried that. Still same problem. All php works except phpmyadmin